# Are chained streams x * O(N)?

Tags: java, java-stream, time-complexity

Assuming the items in the sets stay the same, if I chain a stream after another, after performing some ops, are they now 2 O(N)?

Same with regards to a modified set, is it now O(N) + O(M)?

```java
// o(n)
Stream.of("foo", "bar", "foobar")
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.length() > 3));

// 2O(n)? O(N) + O(M)?
Stream.of("foo", "bar", "foobar")
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.length() > 3))
        .get(true)
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(String::length, Function.identity()));
```

Comment: 2*O(N) is still O(N).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what is being asked here.  What other operation would you expect a stream to implement?  Note that streams have as fairly high overhead (afaik) and if you really need speed a tight loop is better.

Comment: Letting `sorted` aside, most stream operations have O(n) time complexity. But that is no reason to waste memory. The second operation can be written as `Stream.of("foo", "bar", "foobar") .filter(s -> s.length() > 3)) .collect(Collectors.toMap(String::length, Function.identity()));` which will not change the time complexity, but still be faster and need less memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When measuring time complexity, the constants are dropped. O(2N) is the same as O(N).
In the case of streams, it can be looked at like this:

```
for (Item item :items) {
  doSomething1(item);
  doSomething2(item);
}
```

Vs this:

```
for (Item item :items) {
  doSomething1(item);
}

for (Item item :items) {
  doSomething2(item);
}
```

In both cases the time complexity is O(N) overall, where N is the number of items.

Comment: `doSomething` is confusing because it can have exponential complexity. Also the question is partially about stream operations. Modeling it with a simple for loop could be misleading.